# Rearranging Partitions?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

Is it possible to rearrange the order in which hard drive partitions appear on disk?  Of course, there would be no point in doing this to a SSD, but I have heard that for a HDD the operating system closer to the physical outside of the disk will load faster due to less read/write head movement.

Comment: Note that you will need to test yourself. The outer track is usually faster, but just how the outer track is numbered does not have to be the same on each drive. E.g outer most track could be track #0, our track #largerst track number.  (Please ignore that we address blocks these days since early SCSI and ATA-LBA and that if track numbers are shows that these are made up with fake data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible with tools such as [parted](http://www.gnu.org/software/parted/), but this affects sequential access, not random access which is the usual bottleneck with hard drives, so it's not worth the effort, you won't see any difference in everyday usage.

See also: [Does the order of partitions matter?](https://superuser.com/questions/159890/does-the-order-of-partitions-matter)