How good is the long formatting of a hard disk of windows 11, from a security perspective?
I have an old hard disk that I want to completely format. I have found online that the windows quick format deletes the partition table and labels all the data as "Available Space", but the data will remain and can be recovered with some recovery tools.
I have also read the windows long format will overwrite every piece of data with zeros amongst other things. But, despite this, some people will do this process several times or even use junk data instead of zeros.
For those who don't know the windows formatting is the formatting that can be seen when right clicking on a disk in the windows file explorer where it says format... (at least on windows 11).
My question, from a security point of view: Should hard disks be long formatted multiple times or is just one time enough? And what's the benefit of doing the long format multiple times?

Instead of multiple passes of zeroes, interleaved passes of zeroes and ones might be a better option (but yeah you'll need third-party utility to do that)

Before using an old disk, you might want to check the S.M.A.R.T. data to see if it is close to running out of spare sectors. If so, you can disassemble the drive and get a couple of fairly strong magnets from it, and run some sandpaper over the platters if you really want to.

@TomYan But the question is, is a single pass of zeros enough? How does interleaving zeros and ones make it more difficul to extract data than just zeros?

@AndrewMorton Thank you for the suggestion. But, my goal isn't just to destroy the data, but to also know how it would be even possible to recover data if everything has been re-written as zeros.

The purpose of a Windows format (either the quick or full version) is to only create a filesystem in the specified partition of the drive. Such a format has a different/simpler purpose from the now-impossible low-level format of ST506 & IDE HDDs, which actually wrote every "byte" of each track of each platter surface of the HDD. IOW this low-level format even "wrote" the gaps outside the sectors! The modern quick format merely writes the essential sectors to create an empty filesystem, and a full format also clears each data sector.

From a security standpoint, a full format is a low-quality solution. Why bother trying to repeat a better-than-doing-nothing solution? (Zeroing the sectors in a filesystem actually helps later in recovering deleted files.) The full format, regardless of the number of times performed, will still leave the broad outline of the original filesystem as well as the partition table. Instead of wasting time for extra formats, obliterate the entire drive using an appropriate utility such as DBAN.

@sawdust from what I have read online about the long format is it will wipe the partition table in addition to writing zeros in all sectors. I will check out DBAN, thank you!

@MrIzzat - Then you seem to have read misinformation or you misunderstood it. Please provide link(s) instead of repeating this. The last time someone claimed something controversial, it turned out that it was a misunderstanding; see https://superuser.com/questions/643013/are-partitions-to-the-inner-outer-edge-significantly-faster/643634#643634

@sawdust I don't have all the sources at hand but here is one of them: https://www.reddit.com/r/DataHoarder/comments/y58k35/comment/isidskp/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button.

@MrIzzat - IMO (not as a user but as an firmware engineer who has developed a disk controller and written disk drivers and format utilities) that's a poorly worded and inaccurate explanation. Nobody ever wrote that "it will wipe the partition table". You might have inferred that from the misleading/sloppy "overwrites the entire drive". Nobody even mentions "partition" or "filesystem". The use of nonstandard names of formats (e.g. "short", "slow", "long") is a giveaway that these "explanations" are by "experts" that probably learn by using rather than formally trained.

@sawdust If we assume that the during a long format then partition table remains, how would that help discover files in a long formatted hard disk? The partition table could be hundreds of GBs while files can range from 1 kb to 2-3 GBs. It seems like there are way to many possibilites to infer any information solely based on partition table to me. Also, if every sector is filled with zeros, how would the original file system remain?

"If we assume that ... partition table remains" - I know that is fact, so I don't have to assume. You haven't provided any (reliable) source that states otherwise. "Also, if every sector is filled with zeros, how would the original file system remain?" - You're misreading what was written. The new, empty filesystem is still a "broad outline of the original filesystem". You would know exactly the boundaries of the filesystem and where the root directory, allocation table(s), and data sectors are located; there would be no need to guess. That's a big head-start for any recovery effort.

"If we assume that ... partition table remains" - When the drive contains more than one partition/filesystem, the partition table must never be zeroed-out or corrupted when using any format procedure, or else you will unintentionally lose the other partitions/filesystems.

@sawdust, my friend, if we're wiping out a drive that will include wiping out the partition table, since that's what entails wiping out a hard drive completely. I don't need the other partitions if i'm wiping out the hard drive completely. You say there are exact boundaries of an empty filesystem, I don't understand this. If we wipe out a drive completely (of all partitions, of all data etc.) how would there still be boundaries to that file system? Clearly, I'm not an expert on this topic. Would you be kind enough to explain it to me?

If you're trying to "wipe the drive", then yes, by all means clobber the partition table. But as I already wrote, the purpose of the Windows format is to only create a filesystem in the specified partition of the drive. If you want to misuse this system utility to "wipe the partition", then go ahead but do not assume or insist that it should also have capabilities (e.g. "wipe" the partition table or the entire drive) that would render it useless as the intended system utility. You seem to think that the Windows format tool is intended for "wiping the drive", but that is simply wrong.

@sawdust Thank you for your comprehensive answer.

This is kind of an opinion based question.
The question is, when is a secure format required and how secure does it have to be?
Sure, if you do a quick format, almost all recovery tools, including free ones can get the data back.
If you do a long format and write all 0's to the disk, it will be harder for the recovery tools to recover the data, but even then, its not going to be impossible.
Specialized companies can go great lengths to recover data. (but they charge 1000's of $ for their specialized services) Not something the average Joe will use.
The question here is going to be: why do you want to securely erase your drive? What have you had stored on it that cannot fall in the hands of anyone else? If your harddisk was used at home, then the chances are, the people interested in your data are very few people, and the long format is going to suffice.
If your harddisk is from a company and contains very sensitive financial data, you are better off bringing your harddisk to a company specialized in destroying the disk, giving you a certificate of destruction. If anyone gets their hands on your data then, you have a certificate to get all costs blamed om that company.
And yes, there are tools to erase data securely, writing many different kinds of stuff to the drive, and this is useful if you intend to use the drive again afterwards, but it wouldn't make much sense to go through all the effort if the data is not that valuable to begin with. And yes, while precious family photos may be valuable to you, it is not something worth of money to other people. Not even a porn collection would go that far.
So in order to know for yourself if you really have to go through all the lengths, ask yourself this: If a stranger gets your harddisk in their hands, will it cost you money if they get access to the data? If yes, the more money it could cost you, the better of a job you will want to do in securely erase your data.

While I appreciate the more practical approach of your answer, I was more leaning towards finding out the theory behind the practice of doing multiple passes of long format and how it would even be possible to recover old data if all the data is zeros.

I honestly have no clue where you got that question from:
The question is, when is a secure format required and how secure does it have to be?
I wrote plainly what my question is and put it in bold:
Should hard disks be long formatted multiple times or is just one time enough? And what's the benefit of doing the long format multiple times?

Our cyber security insurance requires that drives to be disposed of are physically destroyed.
Physically hdd, must be magnetically wiped and the remains have to be crushed.
So according to them doing a long format is pointless.
As far as re-using it goes, DBAN seems to be a very popular way of erasing them.

Should hard disks be long formatted multiple times or is one time just
enogh? And what's the benefit of doing the long format multiple times?

As far as normal usage, a single zero pass should be sufficient for internal reuse.
The theory for multiple passes with any tool, such as DBAN, is that tiny magnetic traces of the previous data remains that could be recovered.  Now if this is possible, which I don't know, The more passes with random data would scramble the magnetic fields and make the data unreadable.
The theory holds that a government could use an advance technology, such as laser, to detect the previous state of the data.  Equipment like this would surely cost 100+k which would make it impossible for any normal person to buy.
Extremely sensitive magnetic sensors exist, but whether or not that could detect the previous magnetic fields in a usable way is unknown.  Many people theorize that for the governments of the world with virtually unlimited money it could be possible.

Thank you for the answer. I would agree with you that governments would find great uses with that kind of technology. I had no idea such tools even existed. Do you think the tiny magnetic traces could come from a problem with the mechanical parts of the hard disk when writing the zeros or an intentional design?

@MrIzzat  Part of the issue is each bit is either 1 or 0, but it practical terms there are many variations in the strength of magnetic fields.  So If the signal strength is above the threshold it is a 1 else it is 0.  The hard drive is interested in if it a 1 or zero, but imagine a machine sensitive enough to detect 2000+ levels of magnetic field strength now you can apply data analytics to the resulting data set.  Say a 1 bit is 2000 (made up, for example only) units of strength and a 0 is less than 1500.  Now you have 2 gray areas between 0 and 1499 and 1501 to 2000.

wow! That actually makes a lot of sense. Do you have any sources/resources I can look into to learn more about this?

@MrIzzat  Think on how sensitive the sensors on the James Web Space telescope need to be, but again we could be talking millions of dollars per device.  Anyway, say you wipe the whole drive with 0, but as long as were below 1500 (fictional units) of strength the drive thinks it is a 0.  Now lets pretend, the drive reduced the power from 2000 to 1000 when it overwrote the sector.  If you had a senor capable of detecting it you might be able to say everything that is 1000 units is 1 and below is a zero.  I am sure what I am saying is vastly over simplified.

That explains a lot, thank you very much. Do you know where I can learn more about this? @cybernard

@JoepvanSteen will check it out thank you!
